# What happened to the safe maker?

Tags: plot-explanation, now-you-see-me

In the end of the movie *Now You See Me*, we come to know how Lionel Shrike died. But what's the deal with the safe maker? The safe maker made a faulty safe that resulted in Lionel's death. Shouldn't Dylan have some vengeance on his mind towards them? I didn't find that apparent in the movie.

Is it possible Tressler is somehow connected here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[He did.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Now_You_See_Me_%28film%29#Plot)

The money that they frame Thaddeus with at the end of the movie is the money stolen from the safe by Jack. That safe is made by Elkhorn, the same company that made the faulty safe that caused the death of Dylan's father.

Whilst it is likely that Elkhorn would either get the money back after it is released from evidence, or claim it back on insurance, their reputation would have been irreparably tarnished.

Considering the publicity of the stunts that the Four Horsemen preformed, the theft of the money and Thaddeus's trial would have been widely known. The fact that so much money was stolen from a safe created by Elkhorn would have ensured that their name would be forever synonymous with the trial.

This means that anytime anyone wanted to purchase a safe from Elkhorn, they would remember that an incredible amount of money would have been stolen from one of their safes, and likely shop elsewhere, losing them a lot of business and possibly leading to their going bankrupt (or such was Dylan's hope). At the minimum, they would lose business and possibly have to rebrand, probably getting many executives fired in the process.

Comment: Whats the name of the company of the safe maker...? Why was there so much money in that safe in the first place? When in the movie do they first mention this?

Comment: @deostroll I've edited my answer to include the name of the safe company, Elkhorn. And I can't quite remember why there is so much money in the safe, but it's likely that Dylan set up the Four Horsemen stunts to coincide with an Elkhorn safe holding so much money in order for them to be able to steal it. It is explained by Dylan/Rhodes near the end when he is explaining to Alma (the Interpol agent) at the Pont des Arts how and why he manufactured the thefts.